# Fast double click causes code to error

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which is used to control a flip animation.  Everything works fine with a normal click.

However, it seems a fast double click causes 2 events to pass through the boolean check which is supposed to prevent this problem.  In console.log I expect to see 'started running' for the first process and 'already running' for the second click - instead both clicks seem to make it through and cause havoc with the later logic.

Would someone mind letting me know what am I doing wrong and how to avoid this problem?

Thanks,

```
$('.item').each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.data('running', false);

    elem.bind("click",function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();

        if (elem.data('running') == false) {
             elem.data('running', true);
             console.log('started running');
             //do some stuff
             elem.data('running', false);
        } else { 
             console.log('already running'); 
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Why aren't you just doing `$('.item').bind('click', ...)`? You don't need a horrible loop then, and you can reference the clicked element with `$(this)`

Comment: I wish i could give you the point - I got rid of the redundant each and now all seems well.  it's strange i can never get 'already running' to appear in the console, but at least now the problems of the fast clicking just don't occur.  thanks a lot

Comment: Not a problem, and don't worry about the rep `:P`

Answer (score 0):

You are turning off "running" right after you initialize your animation, not after you complete your animation. For example I would do it like this:

```
if (!elem.data('running')) {
     elem.data('running', true);
     console.log('started running');
     elem.fadeOut('fast',function(){
         elem.data('running', false);
     });
}
```